# Adding to pandas df in while loop

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a df that looks like this called full_senator_df:

```
    Official Twitter    Senator         party
0   SenShelby           Richard Shelby  Republican
1   lisamurkowski       Lisa Murkowski  Republican
2   SenDanSullivan      Dan Sullivan    Republican
```

I've written some code to use that data to retrieve tweets for each of these senators. Is there away to append the results to a table or get the results as a json rather than the print it's currently doing?

```
senator_count = 0
num_senators = len(full_senator_df.index)

while senator_count <= num_senators:
    senator_official_twitter = full_senator_df['Official Twitter'][senator_count]
    tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = senator_official_twitter, count = tweet_num, include_rts = True)

    for status in tweets:
        print(full_senator_df['Senator'][senator_count], status.text, full_senator_df['party'][senator_count])

    senator_count += 1
```

[Current Output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI4fi.png)

Comment: can you please post the screenshot of how the print output looks like?

Comment: Added output image

Comment: so youu want to merge data in to a single dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code creates a new dataframe (table) with tweets per senator per party

```
# Create an empty dataframe stub to append to later
all_tweets_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Senator', 'Party', 'Tweet'])

# Iterate over the initial dataframe
for _, row in full_senator_df.iterrows():
    tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = row['Official Twitter'],
                               count = tweet_num,
                               include_rts = True)
    senator_tweets_df = pd.DataFrame({'Senator': row['Senator'],
                                      'Party': row['party'],
                                      'Tweet': tweets})
    # Append to the output
    all_tweets_df = pd.concat([all_tweets_df, senator_tweets_df], sort=True)
```

The output should be something like

```
        Party    Senator   Tweet
0  Republican     Shelby  tweet1
1  Republican     Shelby  tweet2
2  Republican     Shelby  tweet3
0  Republican  Murkowski  tweet1
1  Republican  Murkowski  tweet2
2  Republican  Murkowski  tweet3
0  Republican   Sullivan  tweet1
1  Republican   Sullivan  tweet2
2  Republican   Sullivan  tweet3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are almost there. If you want to keep your loop, instead of printing you can load that data into a dataframe. First define a new dataframe

```
dfTweets = pd.DataFrame() # place this before your while loop
row_num = 0
while ...
...
    for status in tweets:
        dfTweets.loc[0, row_num] = full_senator_df['Senator'][senator_count]
        dfTweets.loc[1, row_num] = status.text, 
        dfTweets.loc[2, row_num] = full_senator_df['party'][senator_count]
        row_num += 1

dfTweets.columns = ["Senator", "tweet_text"]
```